# Notepad++ Newbie - How to delete everything after a specific word?

Tags: notepad++

I have a list in notepad++ with about 296 lines on it. How can i delete everything after inactive? When i try on my own it finds all instances of inactive.

This is what it looks like originally for an example:

```
access-list 101 permit ip 192.168.10.0 0.0.0.255 inactive (hx0000) (123456789) blahblahblah (inactive)
```

I need it to look like this:

```
access-list 101 permit ip 192.168.10.0 0.0.0.255 inactive
```

Question 2:
If for example i wanted to only delete (hx0000) including the parenthesis how would i do this as well? When i try it deletes the text, but makes the output look like this: ()

Thanks in advance everyone!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to delete everything after the first occurrence of `inactive`, you can try the following find and replace:

**Find:**

```
inactive.*
```

**Replace:**

```
inactive
```

Comment: That worked like a charm!! Thanks Tim i really appreciate it mate :)

Comment: @jwalk_pv2001   - you could upvote his answer as well.

Comment: @ G5W - I tried to upvote but I have less than 15 reputation so you won't see the change publicy